# SDL_QUIT events work with g++ but not gcc

Tags: c, gcc, sdl, sdl-2

I want to use SDL with C rather than C++ but I can't get events to work. 
This code works perfectly if its a .c or cpp file and compiled with g++, also if it's a .cpp file and compiled with gcc. However, if it's a .c file and compiled with gcc it compiles just fine, but the SDL_QUIT event doesn't actually do anything, the window just hangs forever.

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400;


int init();
int loadMedia();
void mainLoop();
void close();

SDL_Window* window =  NULL;
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* helloWorld = NULL;



int main( int argc, char* args[] ){

  if( !init() ){

printf("Failed to initialize!\n"); 

  }
  else{

if( !loadMedia() ){
    printf("Failed to load media!\n");
}
else{
    mainLoop();

  }
}

  close();

  return 0;

}


void mainLoop(){

  int quit = 0;

  SDL_Event e;

  while( !quit ){

    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ){
    if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
        quit = 1;
    }
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface( helloWorld, NULL, screenSurface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
  }

}


int init(){

int success = 1;

//initialize sdl
if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS) < 0){

  printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n" , SDL_GetError() );
  success = 0;
}
  else {

//create window
window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    if( window == NULL ){
      printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
      success = 0;
    }
    else {
      screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );
    }
  }

  return success;
}


int loadMedia(){

  int success = 1;

  helloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("images/helloWorld.bmp");
  if( helloWorld == NULL ){
  printf(" Unable to load image %s! SDL_Error: %s\n", "images/helloWorld.bmp", SDL_GetError() );
  success = 0;
  }
  return success;

}


void close(){

//deallocate surface
SDL_FreeSurface( helloWorld);
helloWorld = NULL;

//Destroy window
SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
window = NULL;

//Quit SDL subsystems
SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: The code in question isn't wrong. What actions are you performing to produce QUIT event? Please make complete compilable minimal example of your problem and include it into the question.

Comment: clicking the X button on the window, does nothing. Also if I add other key or mouse events they do not work in pure C, but switching to c++ compiler or source code results in all the sdl events working properly

Comment: If you insisting on not posting complete example, then the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Sorry i misread your question. updated my first post with full example code. Also I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find your problem to be incredibly funny and surely not obvious.

Your problem caused by you having function with name `close`. This is standard POSIX name for function that closes file descriptors. It conflicts with system function. When `SDL_Init` is called, it connects to X server, queries some values, and disconnects (with `XCloseDisplay`). `XCloseDisplay`, among other things, calls `close` on its socket descriptor. The problem is, you've overridden system `close`, and yours is called instead - so that not only socket remains unclosed, but `SDL_Quit` is called by your code also, which stops any further SDL call.

With C++ linkage, function name gets mangled (mangling is essential for things like function overloading), so its resulting name will be something like `_Z5closev`, which no longer conflicts with system function. In fact, you can get the same problemmatic behaviour in C++ if you'll add `extern "C"` before function declaration.

Workaround is either rename your function (better not use standard names), or add `static` specifier before its declaration, which will limit its linkage to only current translation unit.

Linker doesn't report multiple definition conflict because `close` is marked as weak symbol (note `W` before it):

```
$ nm -D libc-2.19.so | grep close
# <skiped>
000da660 W close
```

Comment: Your answer helped me out - thanks!  The tutorial we are using is this:  http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php

Comment: I couldn't understand why I kept getting a seg fault, can't believe i didnt think of this. facepalm(Keyboard) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's working with me as follows (this is in Mac)

```
gcc main.c -o test -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers  -framework SDL2
```

Now the actual code is

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer


    // Create an application window with the following settings:
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
    );


    // Check that the window was successfully made
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    int quit = 0;
    SDL_Event e;

    while( !quit ){

        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ){
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
                quit = 1;
                printf("Closing the window ...\n");
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Once you close the window, the following message appears in the terminal

```
$ gcc main.c -o test -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers  -framework SDL2 
$ ./test
Closing the window ...
```